# Fixed Dialing Number (FDN) how to create list of allowed numbers programmatically

Tags: android, xamarin, fixed, phone-number, dialing

I would like to create/update the FDN list programmatically. Any idea where this journey should begin?

Maybe somebody before me had similar issue and can help me with this.
For any code examples which will push my work forward I will be very greatful.

I am adding the screenshot (android emulator API17) to make it clear what option I am asking about [android API 17 - FDN options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qbhy1.png). 
To get to this menu you need to tap Phone->"open Menu"->Settings->Fixed Dialing Numbers.

Answer (score 0):

I successfully implemented FDN management. You need to know that turning on/off is impossible from code but list management is possible for 100 percent.

Please review my code : https://github.com/papcio28/lib-contacts/blob/master/contactmodule/src/main/java/pl/urban/android/lib/contactmodule/fdn/FdnProvider.java